# Mac Extended keyboard - numeric keypad numerals not working

Tags: macos, keyboard

Mac Pro (Mid 2010) - 10.13.6

Have gone through usual sys prefs settings. All OK. Have tried resetting pram. Tried safe start but just ignores and starts as per usual.

Using Keyboard Viewer I can see no response when clicking numeric buttons.

**Logging in as other user and works fine.**

Looking at Activity Viewer:
Only difference between 2 users is process keybagd is running on user where num keypad not working.

Clues appreciated.

Comment: Check you don't have MouseKeys switched on - System Prefs > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad. There's also an option in there to switch on/off by tapping the Opt key 5 times [you could just try tapping it 5 times & see if you get the screen advice] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrRs2.png

Comment: Bang on! I rechecked and sure enough it was that sys pref. Must have given a cursory glance. As the Zen master said "pay attention!" Thanks for clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bang on! I rechecked and sure enough, System Preferences MouseKeys was switched on (**System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Mouse & Trackpad**). Must have given a cursory glance. As the Zen master said, "pay attention!" Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score -1):

[Set up file sharing](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/mac) and then compare the two files using [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/).

Comment: That was quick! Will check before going any further. Thansk.

Comment: What two files?

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah the OP has decided to go ahead and edit the question so that my answer does not make any sense. This is answer was for comparing the two log files that were generated respectively from the 2 users that the OP mentions (mentioned maybe at this point) in their post.